# REACT/REDUX Two problems with editing item and key after add item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two problems. I will try to explain it as much as I can.

1. I added item editing features to my code, unfortunately when I accept changes my item doesn't change. The add (almost), remove option works as it should. The update option, however, does not send a request.
2. The second problem is that after a slight change of code to add the function of editing the element, my code for adding the element broke a bit. After completing the form and sending it, the element is added, BUT is added without an ID code and I get the error: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` After refreshing the page, the problem disappears, the previously added item already has an ID and is displayed correctly.

PROBLEM NUMBER 1

TaskDetail.js component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getTask, updateTask } from "../../actions/tasks";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class TaskDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      date: "",
      hours: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTask(this.props.match.params.id);
    setTimeout(() => this.update(), 50);
  }

  update = () => {
    console.log("STATE UPDATE");
    const { title, description, date, hours } = this.props.task[0];
    this.setState({
      title: title,
      description: description,
      date: date,
      hours: hours,
    });
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("UPDATE REQUEST");
    const task = {
      title: this.state.title,
      description: this.state.description,
      date: this.state.date,
      hours: this.state.hour,
    };
    this.props.updateTask(this.props.task.id, task);
  };

  render() {
    const { title, description, date, hours } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="card mt-5">
        <div className="card-header">
          <span>ID: {this.props.match.params.id}</span>
        </div>
        <form
          className="card-body"
          onSubmit={this.props.updateTask.bind(
            this.props.match.params.id,
            this.state
          )}
        >
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              name="title"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={title || ""}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              name="description"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={description || ""}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="date-hours-form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Date</label>
              <input
                type="date"
                className="form-control"
                name="date"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={date || ""}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Hours</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                name="hours"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={hours || ""}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-block btn-suc">
              EDIT TASK
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  task: state.tasks.task,
  isLoading: state.tasks.isLoading,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTask, updateTask })(TaskDetail);
```

tasksAction.js

```
// UPDATE TASK
export const updateTask = (id, task) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log(`ID: ${id} TASK: ${task}`);
  axios
    .put(`/api/tasks/${id}/`, task)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_TASK,
        payload: task,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response));
};
```

tasksReducser.js

```
import {
  GET_TASKS,
  DELETE_TASK,
  CREATE_TASK,
  GET_TASK_REQUEST,
  GET_TASK_SUCCESS,
  UPDATE_TASK,
} from "../actions/types.js";

const initialState = {
  tasks: [],
  task: {},
  isLoading: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TASKS:
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: action.payload,
      };
    case DELETE_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: state.tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== action.payload),
      };
    case CREATE_TASK:
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload],
      };
    case GET_TASK_REQUEST:
      console.log("TASK GET PENDING");
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: action.payload.loading,
      };
    case GET_TASK_SUCCESS:
      console.log("TASK GET SUCCESS");
      return {
        ...state,
        task: state.tasks.filter((task) => task.id === action.payload.data.id),
        isLoading: action.payload.loading,
      };
    case UPDATE_TASK:
      console.log("TASK UPDATED");
      return {
        ...state,
        task: {},
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

PROBLEM NUMBER 2

TasksList.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getTasks, deleteTask, getTask } from "../../actions/tasks";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export class Tasks extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getTasks: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteTask: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card card-tasks card-body mt-3">
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Hours</th>
              <th scope="col"></th>
              <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
              <Fragment key={task.id}>
                <tr>
                  <th>{task.id}</th>
                  <td>{task.title}</td>
                  <td>{task.date}</td>
                  <td>{task.hours}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link
                      to={{
                        pathname: `/edit/${task.id}`,
                        state: { id: task.id },
                      }}
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                    >
                      DETAIL
                    </Link>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      onClick={this.props.deleteTask.bind(this, task.id)}
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                    >
                      DELETE
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </Fragment>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  tasks: state.tasks.tasks,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTasks, deleteTask, getTask })(
  Tasks
);
```

Comment: When you look at the redux dev tools can you see the actions that are dispatched and the effect it has on the state and provide the relevant information in your question about what exactly isn't working? You can check the actions aren't there but I assume they are thunk actions that connect to an api so you can check your network tab and confirm that part is working.

Comment: Hi! On problem 1, does the page reflect the updates to tasks after refreshing? On problem 2, can you try consoling the payload of `CREATE_TASK ` action and see if it includes an id? It would also help if you can share the code for createTask action here.